# CkFinder in ASp.Net - MVC2 MVC.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, ckfinder

Anyone managed to get CkFinder working in an MVC2 or MVC3 application? Otherwise, are there any alternatives? I need to give users access to a folder (each user have their own folder) to upload multiple images and CSS files and create subfolders.

I'm already using CkEditor, and would love to get CkFinder working, but I'm MVC beginner and don't know where to start.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide seems like CKEditor intergrates with ASP.NET webforms out the box so you could always have your MVC site link to a webforms site or include asp.x pages into a MVC project.

However if you just want to get image uploading working for CKEditor and not CKFinder implemented, then these 2 URLS will help get the file uploader and brower working.

http://arturito.net/2010/11/03/file-and-image-upload-with-asp-net-mvc2-with-ckeditor-wysiwyg-rich-text-editor/

http://webcmd.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/rich-text-editing-with-ckeditor-mvc-3-and-the-razor-engine/

Comment: I just spent the last 20 minutes doing this as I needed it myself. It works perfectly. Just add the CKFinder.dll to the project, copy the entire CKFinder folder to your /content folder, change the config paths to point to /content/ckfinder, finally add _samples\aspx\standalone.aspx into the Root folder of your MVC project and your done =).

Comment: So basically I need a standard aspx page to use CkFinder? I'd use an iFrame to include that page in a View?

Comment: @Daveo cant understood to change in config file

Comment: @Daveo please tell me how to use standalone page in mvc4 as i done with as you said.